# How to read the data within all keys from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the data of all users(including logged in user).The problem I faced is that by using my following code I ended up reading the data of only logged in user(let key is 01Rn.. ),while I want to retrieve all the data(FJHdk.. key's also ) .

I want to show the data within keys 01Rn...and FJHdk...under books node.But I am only getting the data within 01Rn...key.

> Uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
>
> mdatabasereference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Sell").child("Books").child(Uid);

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<b_ooks> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<b_ooks>()
                                                   .setQuery(mdatabasereference,b_ooks.class)
                                                   .build();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<b_ooks,booksViewHolder> recyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<b_ooks, booksViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final booksViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final b_ooks model) {


            mdatabasereference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     for(DataSnapshot postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                           for (DataSnapshot data : postsnapshot.getChildren()) {
                             holder.Title.setText(model.getTitle());
                             holder.Price.setText(model.getPrice());
                         }

                     }
```

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKz97.jpg)

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process the books for all users, create your a reference to the data one level higher in the JSON:

```
DatabaseReference booksRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Sell").child("Books");
```

And then add an extra look in your `onDataChange` to loop over the user nodes in in the `DataSnapshot`:

```
booksRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot bookSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                System.out.println(bookSnapshot.getKey());
                System.out.println(bookSnapshot.child("Title").getValue(String.class));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's still showing only the layout which I have created in my xml file but is unable to read the data from the database.

Comment: My code intentionally only logs. If the logging doesn't appear, the problem has nothing to do with your layouts. If the logging appears, the problem has nothing to do with your database. It sounds like you're unable to read from the database, so I recommend that you check if you `onCancelled` is getting called. The simplest useful implementation of that method is `throw databaseError.toException();`.

Comment: still not showing . even the message also not showing which I have added in log section in oncancelled method

Comment: If neither `onDataChange` nor `onCancelled` gets called, it's most likely that you're not connected to Firebase to begin with.

Comment: Yes,your code logs correctly. I have checked that on debug console but when I am using " holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());" to show the data then  It is not showing anything there !!!!

Comment: The code you shared doesn't populate `model`. Are you missing a call like `bookSnapshot.getValue(b_ooks.class)`?

Comment: You'd put that right after where you have the `DataSnapshot` that contains the date for a `b_ooks` object. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events